# Загрузка данных в таблицу Lua из файла

Tags: lua

Я хочу загружать тестовые вопросы из разных файлов в таблицу Lua для дальнейшей обработки. Вопросы в файлы будут вноситься вручную. Есть два вопроса.

Вот такой вариант помогли реализовать на этом форуме:

Загрузка данных в таблицу Lua:

```
function loadtbl()
    local filename = "vved_v_bd_test.lua"
    tbl = dofile(filename)
end
```

Файл с данными `vved_v_bd_test.lua` :

```
return 
    { 
    [1] = 
        { 
        ["q"] = "Применение информационной системы реализует?",
        [1] = "{=1}~надежное хранение информации",
        [2] = "{=2}~выполнение специфических для данного приложения преобразований информации и вычислений",
        [3] = "{=3}~предоставление пользователям удобного интерфейса взаимодействия",
        [4] = "{=4}~все вышеперечисленное",
        ["a"] = 4,
        },
    [2] = 
        { 
        ["q"] = "Что из перечисленного не является информационной системой?",
        [1] = "{=1}~автоматизированные системы управления предприятиями",
        [2] = "{=2}~системы резервирования авиационных или железнодорожных билетов",
        [3] = "{=3}~система кодирования",
        ["a"] = 3,
        },
    [3] = 
        { 
        ["q"] = "В 1951 году выпущен первый коммерческий серийный компьютер, как он назывался?",
        [1] = "{=1}~Mac~I",
        [2] = "{=2}~Mac Pro",
        [3] = "{=3}~IBM",
        [4] = "{=4}~UNIVAC~I",
        ["a"] = 4,
        },
    }
```

**1. Можно каким-то образом в файле `vved_v_bd_test.lua` элементы таблицы нумеровать не в ручную (1, 2, 3). Через переменную с инкрементом или как-то еще?**

Возможно есть аналогичное решение через команды вставки в таблицу:

```
table.insert(tbl, {q="Какое из свойств \\textbf{реляционной алгебры} представлено далее?\\par \\begin{equation*} \\begin{aligned}U(U(R, S), T) &\\rightarrow U(R, U(S, T)) \\\\ CP(CP(R, S), T) &\\rightarrow CP(R, CP(S, T)) \\\\ J_{F_2}(J_{F_1}(R, S), T)&\\rightarrow J_{F_1}(R, J_{F_2}(S, T)) \\end{aligned} \\end{equation*}",
a=2,
[1]="{=1}~Коммутативность",
[2]="{=2}~Ассоциативность бинарных операций",
[3]="{=3}~Идемпотентность унарных операций",
[4]="{=4}~Дистрибутивность бинарных операций между бинарными",
[5]="{=5}~Факторизация унарных операций"
})

table.insert(tbl, {q="Триггер это \\ldots~?",
a=1,
[1]="{=1}~Процедура \\textbf{БД}, автоматически вызываемая \\textbf{SQL}~-- сервером при обновлении, удалении или добавлении новой записи в таблицах \\textbf{БД}",
[2]="{=2}~Процедура \\textbf{БД}, вручную вызываемая \\textbf{SQL}~-- сервером при обновлении, удалении или добавлении новой записи в таблицах \\textbf{БД}",
[3]="{=3}~Модуль, написанный на любом языке, который выполняет групповое изменение данных в \\textbf{БД}",
[4]="{=4}~Модуль, написанный на процедурном языке и хранящийся в \\textbf{БД} как метаданные, который можно вызывать из программы"
})
```

**2. Вставить эти команды insert во внешний файл и из него сохранять в заданную таблицу Lua?**

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

конечно можно, вообще `insert` редко когда нужен бывает:

```
local s = {"abcd","foo","bar"}

local t = {}
for k,v in pairs(s) do
   t[#t+1] = v
end

print(table.concat(t,"\n"))
```

результат:

```
abcd
foo
bar
```

Comment: Спасибо, @Mike V. . Все заработало!